# An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again

Tags: error

Mangeto - sigh what a pos sometimes
with that out of my system im getting this error 
all im using is authorized.net on magento 2.1.7 after 10 hours of trying to upgrade im forced to try and figure out how to resolve this. 
ive changed the code in the paymentinformatimanagement.php but it doesnt show me any debug when checking out.
An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.

so fustrated with this software i regret moving to it.

https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-checkout-debuggen/

[2018-08-18 00:31:02] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'The transaction was declined because the response hash validation failed.' in /home/devclvigilant1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:542

so i logged into authorized created md5 applied to site
the site seamed to go to a new page heres a custom addon trying to remove.
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/devclvigilant1/public_html/app/code/Aitoc/CustomProductDesigner/Observer/OrderCreateAfter.php on line 116

chown -R username: path i did the whole thing
site loads and was able to purchase!! jeeeez

Comment: Please check console and post error here, and if you have modified any core code then please revert it.

Comment: https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-upgrade
none of these options worked as far as upgrade goes